# Convert double [] to Eigen::Matrix4d

Tags: c++, matrix, double, mapping, eigen

I am not able to understand how to convert an array of double [] to the Eigen::Matrix4d type.

I am trying by doing:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d transform = map<Eigen::Matrix4d>(M->data,M->nrows,M->ncols);
```

Where M is : `matd_t *M`

```
typedef struct
{
    int nrows, ncols;
    double data[];
//    double *data;
} matd_t;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This was pretty a stupid error :)

I found my solution:

```
Eigen::Matrix4d transform = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix4d>(M->data,M->nrows,M->ncols);
```

Basically I was using the C++ `map` instead of the Eigen Map function.

Now it works.

Comment: Note that you can name it to directly use your data during the computation: `Map<Matrix4d> transform(M->data);`

Comment: Also, if you want to initialize a fixed-sized matrix (or vector) to values from raw memory, you can use the raw-pointer constructor: `Eigen::Matrix4d transform(M->data);` (this copies the values instead of mapping).